# Entity Framework: Update object failed with duplicate key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a class `Activity`, it associate with some departments.

```
public class Activity
{
...

    public int Id { get; set; }




    public virtual List<Department> ParticipantDepartments { get; set; }


}
```

Here is the Action in Controller, which accept a user's editing. Before user's editing, the `activity` already associated with some `ParticipantDepartments` in the database. Now We assume user modify `ParticipantDepartments`, then in POST method I change `ParticipantDepartments` to the new user defined one:

```
 // POST: Activities/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(
         EditActivityViewModel editActivityViewModel)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Activity activity = db.Activities.Find(editActivityViewModel.ActivityId);

                activity.
                    Category = editActivityViewModel.Category;
                activity.DetailedLocation = editActivityViewModel.DetailedLocation;
                activity.District = editActivityViewModel.District;
                activity.Linkman = editActivityViewModel.Linkman;
                activity.Phone = editActivityViewModel.Phone;
                activity.Title = editActivityViewModel.Title;
                activity.TotalParticipantsAmount = editActivityViewModel.TotalParticipantsAmount;
                activity.particular = editActivityViewModel.particular;
                activity.OriginatorId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                activity.ParticipantDepartments = GetParticipantDepartments(editActivityViewModel.SelectedDepartmentIds);

                List<Models.ActivityTime> activityTimes = new List<Models.ActivityTime>();
                foreach (var item in editActivityViewModel.ActivityTimes)
                {
                    Models.ActivityTime activityTime = new Models.ActivityTime
                    {
                        StartTime = item.StartDate + item.StartTime,
                        EndTime = item.EndDate + item.Endtime
                    };
                    activityTimes.Add(activityTime);
                }
                activity.AcvitityTimes = activityTimes;


                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(editActivityViewModel);
        }
```

However, asp.net hint that

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.DepartmentActivities'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DepartmentActivities'. The
>   duplicate key value is (13, 1008).
> The statement has been
>   terminated.

It happened when user modify `ParticipantDepartments`, but there are still some department same as before, which is acceptable. However, Entity Framework seemed not know about it. So it just insert a new record in table `dbo.DepartmentActivities`.

Question is, how to fix this problem? Should I find some way to "first remove all associated departments in the database, and then update `activity` like I post here, or should I find some way to let Entity Framework know about I have already associated some departments with `activity`?

---

Edit:

```
  private List<Department> GetParticipantDepartments(List<List<int>> selectedDepartmentIds)
        {
            List<Department> departments = new List<Department>();
            foreach (var selectedDepartmentId in selectedDepartmentIds)
            {
                departments.Add(AccountController.GetDepartment(selectedDepartmentId, db));
            }
            return departments;
        }
```

Comment: can you show me GetParticipantDepartments(editActivityViewModel.SelectedDepartmentIds); method

Comment: @jitender See the update please.

Comment: @jitender `GetParticipantDepartments` just analyse user's input and return ` List<Department>`

Answer (score 0):

I assume `SelectedDepartmentIds` is `List<int>`

```
 //this will add new departments 

var newDepartmentIds = editActivityViewModel.SelectedDepartmentIds.Where(sdid =>  activity.ParticipantDepartments.All(pd => pd.Id != sdid)).ToList();

activity.ParticipantDepartments.Add(GetParticipantDepartments(newDepartmentIds));

//if you also want to remove the departments those are not in editActivityViewModel.SelectedDepartmentIds

activity.ParticipantDepartments.RemoveRange(activity.ParticipantDepartments.Where(apd => editActivityViewModel.SelectedDepartmentIds.All(sdid => sdid != apd.Id)))
```